# R : problem in installing package 'Frostarella/DSUR.noof'

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to install DSUR.noof package from GitHub and followed the instructions accordingly

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("Frostarella/DSUR.noof")
```

When I try to run the last command`(install_github("Frostarella/DSUR.noof")` I am getting the below error in Rstudio

```
Error: 'setInternet2' is defunct.
```

what could went wrong ? can some one help me

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Sweden.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_Sweden.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Sweden.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] usethis_1.4.0  devtools_2.0.1 ggplot2_3.1.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18      pillar_1.3.0      compiler_3.5.1   
 [4] plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1.1       remotes_2.0.2    
 [7] prettyunits_1.0.2 tools_3.5.1       digest_0.6.15    
[10] pkgbuild_1.0.2    pkgload_1.0.2     memoise_1.1.0    
[13] tibble_1.4.2      gtable_0.2.0      pkgconfig_2.0.1  
[16] rlang_0.2.1       cli_1.0.0         rstudioapi_0.7   
[19] yaml_2.2.0        bindrcpp_0.2.2    withr_2.1.2      
[22] dplyr_0.7.6       fs_1.2.6          desc_1.2.0       
[25] rprojroot_1.3-2   grid_3.5.1        tidyselect_0.2.4 
[28] glue_1.3.0        R6_2.2.2          processx_3.2.1   
[31] sessioninfo_1.1.1 purrr_0.2.5       callr_3.1.1      
[34] magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.2   scales_1.0.0     
[37] ps_1.3.0          assertthat_0.2.0  colorspace_1.4-0 
[40] labeling_0.3      lazyeval_0.2.1    munsell_0.5.0    
[43] crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: can't reproduce

Comment: Please add output of `sessionInfo()` to your post.

Comment: Hello Richard ,R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: zx8754 , Now I have attached sessionInfo() to my post

Answer (score 0):

I was running on Anaconda Rstudio before, then installed CRAN R problem solved.....